# Repository for Family Pictures

Tags: ssh, mount, git, repository, file-sharing

I have a Debian computer and a MacBook Air. On Debian I created a repository:

```
mkdir -p /repository/git/2014.git
cd /repository/git/2014.git
git init --bare --shared
```

On the MacBook I then typed:

```
cd /path/to/2014-pictures
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin lozsui@debianbox:/repository/git/2014.git
git push origin master
```

Now, `git add .` and `git push origin master` took quite some time.

I chose this approach because I find it quite easy to apply. In case some new pictures will be added on MacBook I can `git push origin master` them quite easy to `debianbox:/repository/git/2014.git` again. Moreover, I get a versioning along the way.

When I am sitting in front of my Debian computer I simply do `git clone /repository/git/2014.git /to/bring/pictures/to/the/place/I/need/them`.

Now, do you folks know better ways to achieve what I basically want to do?

Comment: Versioning for pictures? What is the benefit of that? You could use a tool like [syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) to automate the process...

Comment: @jasonwryan - great suggestion, I hadn't heard of that tool before. Been using SparkleShare but that uses Git as it's backend; similar to Dropbox, but not a good fit for this particular Q.

Comment: I hope you realise that you will at least double the storage requirements for the pictures, on each machine, by using `git`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Git in this manner is a really bad idea. It's not meant to store binary data, so every time you revision an identical image you'll be keeping both copies (old + new). Plus it's not really the fastest thing for moving this type of data around.

If your heart is set on the Git interface you could use [`git-annex`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) instead. It makes use of the Git U/I but allows the "backends" to be swapped out for ones that are better suited to binary data.

*excerpt*

> git-annex allows managing files with git, without checking the file
>   contents into git. While that may seem paradoxical, it is useful when
>   dealing with files larger than git can currently easily handle,
>   whether due to limitations in memory, time, or disk space.
>
> git-annex is designed for git users who love the command line. For
>   everyone else, the git-annex assistant turns git-annex into an easy to
>   use folder synchroniser.